# RelaxNG Debug Message for Choice Elements

Tags: perl, relaxng

How do I make my RNG file more verbose so that if I fail to specify a required choice element, the error message will be better described than just:

```
Expected an element , got nothing
```

Is there a way to name the choice tag?

Comment: RelaxNG is the name of a language. Which software are you talking about that throws this error message?

Comment: The "Expected an element , got nothing" message indicates libxml2.

Answer (score 0):

RelaxNG has no system for defining human readable error text based on such conditions. As @daxim hinted, any ability to note a failure to fulfill required choice elements would be up to the software running the validation.

A possible solution would be to use Schematron, which is designed to output specific messages for such tests.